# Function that creates a directory and then reading the file from that new directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to run this function and then read the file with fs.readFile

```
function download(url){
    mkdirp('/directory', function(err) {
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/directory/example.txt));
    });
}
```

How would I do this asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

Install it like this
`npm i fs-extra`

An example snippet for your use case could be:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra')

function download(url){
  // ensureDir creates the directorie(s) if not exist
  fs.ensureDir(path.join(__dirname, '/directory'), err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`failed to create directory`)
      return false
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/directory/example.txt'), 'YOUR-TEXT-TO-WRITE-INTO-THE-FILE')
    console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/directory/example.txt')))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a read stream pipe once the first pipe has finished.

```
function download(url) {
    mkdirp('/directory', function(err) {
        request(url)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/directory/example.txt'))
            .on('finish', function() {
                fs.createReadStream('/directory/example.txt').pipe(process.stdout);
            });
        ;
    });
}
```

You can of course pipe it to somewhere else other than process.stdout.